# "...std::filesystem functions not found" when running ./configure

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to compile [this](https://gitlab.com/german.tischler/libmaus2) library on ubuntu 18.04. When I run `./configure` I get the following error:

```
checking whether std::move exists... yes
checking whether std::filesystem exists... no
configure: error: Required std::filesystem functions not found
```

Do you know how to fix this error? Whan functions is it talking about? I don't know C++ so I am lost.

Comment: Your compiler is probably too old. What version do you have? Have you considered using an older version of the *library* which doesn't require `std::filesystem` (if possible)? Or perhaps you need to invoke the `configure` script with flags to disable the use of `std::filesystem`?

Comment: If that's gcc, filesystem was implemented relatively late, no earlier than  v.8, which is way past C++17

Comment: So I checked the versions of my g++ and c++ compilers. It looks like they are both 7.5.0. Any tips on how to update them?

Comment: I'd start with the package manager, but that would probably require you to update your distribution. Speaking of, I'm not off base assuming you're using a *nix system?

Comment: Yes, I am on ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my gcc/g++ compiler was outdated. Installation of 9.0 version using [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-ubuntu-18-04/) tutorial solved the problem.